# How to access library version details in JavaScript

Tags: 8, javascript

I have a theme with library file looks like this:

```
global:
  version: 1.0.0
  js:
    js/global.js: {}
```

global.js has some functionality specific to version 1.0.0.

Is there anyway to get this version number? Is it available in JS?

Answer (score 2):

Library definitions can be accessed via the `library.discovery` service ([LibraryDiscovery](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Asset!LibraryDiscovery.php/class/LibraryDiscovery/8.2.x)).

```
$libraryDiscovery = \Drupal::get('library.discovery');
// Where mytheme is the name of your theme.
$definition = $libraryDiscovery->getLibraryByName('mytheme/global');
```

Then you would need to pull out `$definition['version']` into a JavaScript settings or do something with it in your theme.

Comment: Thanks.I will give this option a try. Thought there might be some kinda out-of-box option available as version could be essential.

Comment: This is out of the box. It is within core API.